# Make the store my homepage?

Tags: home

Right now my store is located at www.example.com/store

How do change that so that when I type www.example.com it goes to the store? Right now it goes to what I was trying to design before. I don't want that.

Thanks!

Rachel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that base url is set to http://www.example.com/ instead of http://www.example.com/store/

Check @ Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Web -> Unsecure -> Base URL

*Note the trailing /*

Comment: I did that and now it is all messed up and gives me a 500 error. :) How do I revert it back? It won't let me.

Comment: You can revert it by connecting to your database by PHPMyAdmin or any MySQL client and executing the following query when you are on the database of your store.
`UPDATE \`core_config_data\` SET \`value\` = 'http://www.example.com/store/' WHERE \`path\` = 'web/unsecure/base_url' AND \`scope\` = 'default' AND \`scope_id\` = 0;`

Than delete all content of /var/cache/ to flush the cache manually and try to open the website.